# Select option disabled and selected - only CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm facing to a some trouble with a select option disabled but auto selected.

I want to show a default value into the select when at the page is loadded so I use this code:

```
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Select your item</option>
  <option>item</option>
  <option>item</option>
</select>
```

But when the user open the select list, I would like to hide the option or stylized the option but I don't know how to get it in my CSS. 
Or if I try to hide the option it doesn't work in IE (min ie11).

I tried to get it with

```
select option[disabled]:selected
select option[disabled]:focus 
etc
```

but no result for the moment, the disabled selected option still have the default behavior, I can see my change only when I hover other items.

Idee?

Comment: you want to hide <option disabled selected>Select your item</option> and show others on page load?

Comment: you wont dropdown option or not or else disable select  ..!

Comment: can you elaborate your question that which option you want to disable and which option you want to hide? there is a bit of confusion for me in your question.

Answer (score 1):

try this if look like your requirement

```html
<select>
  <option hidden>Select your item</option>
  <option>item</option>
  <option>item</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that question is a bit old but I come over this when I tried something similar today.
If you want to apply different styles to the pre-selected option and the actual options and also not want to show the pre-selection in the dropdown try this:

```css
select:invalid {
  color: #BDBDBD;
}     
select option {
  color: #4c4643;
}
```

```html
<select required="">
  <option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">Select please</option>
  <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Counter-intuitively, this seems to work in Chrome.

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected hidden>Select your item</option>
  <option>item</option>
  <option>item</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize options on focus. Try this.

```
select:focus option{
    background-color: red;
}
```